# Export html page with data(Grid view) and images to excel in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Title may not describing well what I'm asking for, 
Actually I'm looking for some guidelines to solve my code issue,

> I'm creating a application that will export the HTML page with data in
>   Grid view and logo images to excel. What I've done so far in below:

```
private void ExportExcel()
    {
        //This method is defined in ButtonClick Event
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Charset = "";
        GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
        string FileName = "Exported" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
        StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        this.EnableViewState = false;
        GridView2.DataBind();
        Response.Write(ExportDiv.InnerHtml);
        GridView2.GridLines = System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridLines.Both;
        GridView2.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        GridView2.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
        Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

This above code is working fine, but they issue is with the logo image Attach images shows issue with logo image,
[Check Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaSH2.png)

> The logo image is not set inside a cell what i actually need. What i
>   need is shown in this pic [Please check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz9Yp.png)

Comment: I cannot directly add image please some edit my question add images..

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Comment: PS where did you get that piece of code to export to Excel using `HtmlTextWriter`?

Comment: I cannot use library,

Comment: @VDWWD Did you check what I'm asking for?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you are generating html, not an Excel file.

Comment: Okay I understand, I'm new to EPPlus library. Please send me documentation or something to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Without using any outsource library you can do this, Things that was causing issue the alignment of the Grid view and HTML code.

> So what I've done is create a div and named it `ExportDiv` and add
>   HTML Table inside `ExportDiv`, after that I write my HTML code inside
>   table by adding row and columns again and again, and add grid view
>   inside my Table which was created inside `ExportDiv`.

Following is the code that works behind the click event.

```
 private void ExportToExcel(string strFileName)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=" + strFileName;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter oStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        GridView3.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView3.DataBind();
        ExportDiv.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
        string style = @"<style> TD { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
        Response.Output.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.End();
    }
```

The good thing about the above code is it set HTML design and Grid view alignment accordingly.

> **Anyone else facing issue in this type of work can ask in comments**
>   **surely help him out.**